# close connection on ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, sql, postgresql, jquery

I have a simple ajax request that can potentially be performed several times in a second. Should I put a `pg_close($con)` at the end of the php file? Will it open hundreds of connections for each ajax request, or will it use the same one it opened at the beginning of the file with `$result = pg_query($con, $query);`?

Thanks!

Comment: You only allowed a certain number of database connections [postgresql-wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections). I would close it always at the end of the script.

Comment: If your script is called once for every AJAX request, it'll open hundreds of connections. Use a connection pool.

Comment: @CraigRinger do you have a good link to a tutorial for that? thanks!

Comment: @thomas The link in Richard's answer should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will close it at the end of the script. Run a connection pooler like [pgbouncer](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgbouncer/) between Apache and pg.

See [Number of connections](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections) in the PostgreSQL wiki.